# DbGeometry serialization issue in Asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, deserialization, spatial

I'm building an OData v3 Web API with Entity Framework 6.0 Code First.

Everything works well and I can execute CRUD operations back to the api server.

However I'm using Spatial Types and some of my entities have DbGeometry properties. When I try to update/post an entity with a DbGeometry type from a client application (just a console application for tests) I get this DataServiceRequestException:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

It took me a while but I identified the `DbGeometry` type as the responsible. I already looked at [this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926102/deserializing-dbgeometry-with-newtonsoft-json/24063543#24063543) and made a custom `JsonConverter`, where I applied to the property:

```
[Required]
[JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeometryConverter))]
[Column("geometria")]
public DbGeometry Geometria { get; set; }
```

That didn't worked. The object is not deserialized on the web api server unless I remove the `DbGeometry` property.

I also tried to change the Global json serializer behavior

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DbGeometryConverter());
```

Also futile. I really need the `DbGeometry` properties. What else can I do to work around this issue?

Comment: What you get bringing the Geometria attribute as object? Eventually it would work out to bring the object and do the conversion in a Mapper.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but for those who'll seek an answer:

I've managed to do it with the exact same code on a controller level. The idea was taken from this [SO Question&Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499041/web-api-configure-json-serializer-settings-on-action-or-controller-level)

So, here is the code including the DbGeometryConverter.

DbGeometryConverter.cs:

```
public class DbGeometryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DbGeometry));
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var location = JObject.Load(reader);
        var token = location["Geometry"]["WellKnownText"];
        string geom = token.ToString();

        token = location["Geometry"]["CoordinateSystemId"];
        int srid = token != null ? int.Parse(token.ToString()) : 0;
        var converted = DbGeometry.FromText(geom, srid);
        return converted;
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

CustomJsonAttribute.cs:

```
public class CustomJsonAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        var formatter = controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DbGeometryConverter());
    }
}
```

And `[CustomJson]` attribute on a controller that uses DbGeometry.