# Api response data not displayed in table (Angular)

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

I get a list/array of categories from my backend and display them in a table but my table is not showing any data in it.
I checked the network tab in inspect, it shows 200 response and gets all the data from api.

**model.ts**

```
export interface Category{
  Id:string;
  Name:string;
  UrlHandle:string;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  addCategory(model:AddCategoryRequest): Observable<void>{
    return this.http.post<void>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/categories`,model);

  }

  getAllCategories(): Observable<Category[]>{
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/categories`);
  }
}
```

**html code**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-3">Category List</h1>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-3">
    <a [routerLink]="['/admin/categories/add']" class="btn btn-primary"
      >Add Category</a
    >
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="categories$ | async as categories">
    <table class="table table-bordered mt-3">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Url Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let category of categories">
          <td>{{ category.Id }}</td>
          <td>{{ category.Name }}</td>
          <td>{{ category.UrlHandle }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**Network tab** for your reference
[image: 200 response]

[image]

I thought I was having problem with my html file, that my code is not allowing the data to be displayed. I checked thoroughly and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can see the response that the fields are camel case, while your `Category` model's properties are in Pascal case. Either modify your `Category` model's properties to camel case or modify your API to return the response fields in Pascal case. The property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: but why are they in camel case? I never typed my properties anywhere in my code in camel case

Comment: I believe this is the default serialization rule in the Web API to set it as camel case. You need to override the default behavior. If you are using [.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892130/8017690), for [.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52766426/8017690) and apply `PascalCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

Comment: Thanks man! I modified my api first but I had the same problem, then I noticed my migration file. Updated migration and database, now it works like a charm